# Intellij Idea 13 Servlet class does not want to be created

Tags: servlets, intellij-idea, ide

I create default SpringMVC project, then choose new->servlet, enter servlet name, press "ok" and ... nothing happens :)

Classes and interfaces are created normally.

Upd: Even more, servlets are created normally in a separate module, if I choose new module -> java and check "web application" in "technologies to use" list. But I just can't copypaste newly created servlet into my main module.

Are there alternative ways of creating a servlet? What needs to be done more than to paste servlet code into a class text window?

Comment: Can you create a new class?

Comment: yes, i can. And interface.

Comment: Enter ⌘+O end type in your servlet name. Do you see it now? On the side note, where do you choose "new->servlet", is it a context menu or main menu?

Comment: I don't recognize this symbol "⌘". I choose servlet from the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have web.xml deploytment descriptor.

1. Open your module settings (F4)
2. Select "Web"
3. Add deployment descriptor